# How to generate JSON request payload with same key and value as array and object?

Tags: json, jackson, pojo, jackson-databind

Example format for my JSON request Payload is below:

```
{
    "A" : [
        {
            "B": {
                "C": "c",
                "D": "d",
            } 
        },
        {
            "B" : [
                {
                    "E": "e",
                    "F": "f"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to generate POJO class for above JSON format with same key B and value as Object and Array.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Create a class having attribute `B`. And `A` will be a list of this new class.

Comment: Could you please provide sample code

Comment: You can try generating from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: I tried using jsonschema2pojo.org for generating POJO classes but issue is I get getter/setter for class B in class A as List<B>. I am not able to set B as Object and as Array value.

Comment: So I have change List<B> to Object. Now I can set both Object/Array as a value to property B. Thanks for the help.